# Flash AS3: How to prevent MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT when you mouse_over a child sprite

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

All,

Here's my situation...

The UI of my Flash application is a grid. Each row of the grid is a sprite that contains a number of child sprites (UI controls) that respond to mouse events

Each row of the grid should have a hover effect - i.e., when you hover over the row, the row's background should change color.

This is accomplished easily:

```
rowSprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, highlightRow, false, 0, true);
rowSprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, unhighlightRow, false, 0, true);
```

This works fine, EXCEPT that when the user rolls over any of the row's child sprites, the row's MOUSE_OUT event is fired, and the row is "unhighlighted". This isn't what I want.

In other words - I'd *like* the row to be unhighlighted only when you roll **OUTSIDE** of the row, not when you roll over a child sprite within the row.

A possible solution: in the `unhighlightRow` function, test whether the user's mouse position is still within the row sprites bounds. But I'm guessing that's not the most elegant or efficient solution.

This must be an incredibly common problem. What's the best solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use ROLL_OVER and ROLL_OUT instead of MOUSE_OVER and MOUSE_OUT in such cases:

http://kinderas.blogspot.com/2008/12/quicktip-mouseover-vs-rollover.html

Comment: This what I was going to suggest, the perfect answer IMO. `MOUSE_OVER`/`MOUSE_OUT` are useless for what you want to do, `ROLL_OVER` will only trigger once when the mouse moves over a `DisplayObject` object and won't trigger any `ROLL_OUT` events due to children. So yeah, I vote for this guy! haha

Comment: yup that is the best solution in this case other than turning off the mouseChildren.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a very common problem, and Adobe have provided a solution.

You can use the `mouseChildren` property - set it to `false` to prevent children generating (yes, generating) mouse related events, which in your case will rid you from unwanted `mouseOut` events as there would be no correspoding `mouseOver` event generated when your cursor enters a childs area.

`mouseChildren` is available for `DisplayObjectContainer` objects.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#mouseChildren

Comment: Since the question says that the children are "sprites (UI controls) that respond to mouse events", setting mouseChildren to false is probably not the solution in this case.

Comment: Lars is correct; `rowSprite.mouseChildren = false` solves my rollout problem, but it prevents the children sprites from responding to mouse events. Thanks for the suggestion, tho

Comment: Indeed. I will post another answer, as I did have a similar situation as I now recall.

Comment: The rowSprite essentially should handle the events of its children. You just track the mouseX and mouseY. Posted the same answer, scanned the pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
rowSprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, highlightRow, false, 0, true);
rowSprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, unhighlightRow, false, 0, true);

function unhighlightRow (e:MouseEvent):void {
   if(Sprite(e.target).contains(e.currentTarget)) {
      return
   }
}
```

didn't test it but it should work

Comment: Lucas, Thanks for this suggestion! However, a few issues... 1) I get an error (`1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject.`). That's correctable, but the bigger issue is that it seems like e.target === e.currentTarget, so the logic fails.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the children from receiving mouse events set.
That would fix your problem:

```
rowSprite.mouseChildren = false;
```